# GNU make - Target with several recipes where only one recipe is needed

Tags: build, makefile, dependencies, gnu-make

### Abstract description

I have the following situation in a Makefile:

```
target_1 target_2 :
    some_recipe_that_creates_both

target_1 :
    some_recipe_that_creates_only_target_1
```

Note that it is impossible to have a recipe that builds `target_2` without `target_1` efficiently. Therefore, if I already need to build `target_2` I would like to avoid running the `target_1`-only recipe. Ideally this would mean make would work as follows:

- If someone tries to make `target_1` without `target_2`, then use the second recipe from the makefile sample since it is faster.
- If someone tries to make `target_1` and `target_2`, use the first recipe from the makefile sample since it is faster than running the recipe that creates both.

Is there a way that I can achieve this? I am aware of double-colon rules, bu they would run both recipes instead of only one of them.

Note that I need a solution that supports make with the `-j` parameter as well (but there is no recursive make).

### The real scenario

The following text is here only for completeness sake and due to comments asking what the real scenario here is, it describes what `target_1` and `target_2` are:

I am compiling a shared library and executables that depend on it. If I finished compiling the shared library, I would like to make sure that the exe still sees all the symbols it needs in it. There are two ways to do it:

- Have the exe linking depend on the shared objects.
- Split exe linking into two steps (with empty marker files as the targets), exe linking, and missing symbol check (`ldd -r`). The problem is that exe linking already implies missing symbols check, so missing symbol check is essentially `target_1`, and linking is doing both `target_1` and `target_2`).

Comment: Question: When you say `second` in `If someone tries to make target_1 without target_2, then use the SECOND recipe since it is faster`, you refer to the second recipe from the code sample or the second one from your statement? The same goes for the second bullet. It makes more sense to think of the code sample, but I just want to confirm.

Comment: @chatraed - Thanks, I fixed my question to be less ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little bit of a hack but something like the following might work

```
ifneq ($(filter target_1,$(if $(filter target_2,$(MAKECMDGOALS)),,$(MAKECMDGOALS))),)
target_1 :
    some_recipe_that_creates_only_target_1
else
target_1 : target_2
endif

target_2 :
    some_recipe_that_creates_both
```

Comment: Nice, but it assumes that target_1 and target_2 are specified directly in the command line. This prevents from using an `all` PHONY which refers to them and to other targets.

Comment: @tohava Updated, it's even more of a hack but it should work for all cases now.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how this works? To me it still looks like it won't work for `make all` because in that case `MAKECMDGOALS` would only contain `all` and not the individual targets

Comment: @tohava If the commandline goals contain 1 but not 2, then the rule that makes only 1 is defined. For every other case, including no commandline goals, 1 is defined in terms of 2. Assuming you have 1 and 2 set as dependencies of `all` this will work for any combination of goals, or when no goals are specified (and `all` is the default goal, which it should be).

Comment: You are correct, but I wanted something more general, so that if I have some phony `phony_target_1` or `phony_target_2` which creates only one of the targets and is specified in the command line it would still work.

Comment: @tohava Why would you need phony targets for that, just say `make target_1`.

Comment: `phony_target_1` was just an oversimplification, but I do have a phony that depends on `target_1` and other unrelated targets

Comment: @tohava I still don't see how that affects the above, you can add any number of additional dependencies to either target.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not see behind that sample provided by you and there are chances I didn't catch the problem in all its details. But, it just feels like the *break down* work of the makefile designer is simply not finished.

In my understanding:

1. If you need to make `target_1` only, there is an existing target `target_1` in the makefile. So, you just use it.
2. If you need to make `target_2` only, there is no such possibility. Why?
3. If you need to make both targets, you use a special recipe that is faster than building the entire `target_1` plus the entire `target_2`, probably because `target_2` builds redundantly a piece from `target_1` (am I right?).

So, it feels like you need something like:

```
target12_common:
    common_piece_absolutely_needed_by_target1_and_by_target2

target2: target12_common
    some_recipe_that_creates_target2_only

target1: target12_common
    some_recipe_that_creates_target1_only

all: target1 target2
```

Is it feasible in your system?

Comment: Check out my edit to the question, it describes what the real scenario is. This is not feasible because the linker will not give a "common piece".

Comment: What is the duration in seconds/minutes of `some_recipe_that_creates_both` ?

Comment: @tohava: what is the expected gain after optimizing your makefile (best/worst case)?

Comment: @chatared - In some cases I know that `ldd -r` takes 4 times less than full linking. The main reason that I am doing it though is not to reduce total build time, but to make the build more incremental, I am trying to shave off roughly 1-10 seconds from an incremental build in which only source file for a shared library used by most executables have changed.